# Android - can I pass a parameter when launch other applications from my application?

Tags: android, android-intent

How to pass a parameter to an application that I call from my Application?

Comment: Your problem is solved at this answer 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923265/android-how-do-i-open-another-app-from-my-app

Answer (score 9):

You're starting your other activity with an Intent. It should look similar to this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then you can add a line of code to pass parameters (e.g. Strings):

```
intent.putExtras("key", "value");
```

Note: you should add this line before starting the activity ;)

Comment: Note that it's putExtra not putExtras. putExtras has another signature.

Comment: Why this answer has got so many upvotes? The question was about calling another Application, so you cannot use 'SecondActivity.class' that is in the code of the second application.