# android: how do i open another app from my app?

Tags: android, api, android-activity

I understand how to use intents and startActivity() when opening another activity within my own app, but how do you start a different app? specifically:

- How do you determine if the user has the needed app installed on their device?
- How do you start that app?
- How do you pass parameters to that app?
- How do you find all this info out for a specific app (say Adobe reader, or google maps)?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**How to see if Intent is available:**

1. Try calling Intent and deal with `ActivityNotFoundException` if it isn't available

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

   try {
       startActivity(intent);
   } 
   catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
       Toast.makeText(OpenPdf.this, 
           "No Application Available to View PDF", 
           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
   ```

   or
2. [Query the Package Manager](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/can-i-use-this-intent.html) to see if it is ahead of time:

   ```
   PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   intent.setType("application/pdf");

   List list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
       PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

   if (list.size() > 0) {
       intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
       startActivity(intent);
   }
   ```

**How to pass parameters to an application or know its capabilities:**

1. [List of Available Intents for Google Applications](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html)
2. [List of Intents by 3rd parties @ OpenIntents](http://www.openintents.org/en/intentstable)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for are **intents** and **intent filters**.

Everything you want to know is detailed on the Android developer guide.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.testing_app");
if (launchIntent != null) {
    startActivity(launchIntent);
} else {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "testing_app is not installed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```