# Is there an Intent for viewing documents (Word, Excel, Powerpoint, PDF, etc.) in Android?

Tags: android, ms-office, android-intent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android: how do i open another app from my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923265/android-how-do-i-open-another-app-from-my-app)

Is there an Intent to view files such as word document (.doc), excel sheet, powerpoint (.ppt), pdf, etc. in Android?

Comment: See this answer, it provides an example of how to open a PDF file via an intent, any PDF-supporting apps will respond and the user can then select one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923265/android-how-do-i-open-another-app-from-my-app

Answer (score 2):

All you can do is, emit intent of specified MIME type. Android will handle what application(s) is capable to open it.

Something like this solution should work: [View MS office files in an android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775295/how-to-view-ms-office-files-in-an-android-application)