# View MS office files in an android application

Tags: java, android, file, ms-office, android-intent

I am trying to view files in my application such as audio, video , PDF and others.

I have successfully done that, now I am trying to view Microsoft office files such as doc, docx, xls and ppt.

Is there any way to do that in android, like calling an Intent?

I am so appreciated for any help or guide.

**Edit**

I have downloaded thinkfree office to my nexus S, but the following code still returning false, kindly look at it:

```
 private boolean checkViewerAvailability(String type) 
 {
    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setType("application/doc");

    List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    return list.size() > 0;
}
```

Comment: May you please share the code you used to show preview of pdf etc?

Comment: Hello, its been almost 5 years now, but I will look up the code for you, anyway i guess this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10530506/488434 is what you're looking for

Comment: Thank you sir, this is via an intent right, not in-app preview?

Comment: Yes via Intent, are you looking for in app preview? What type of files are you targeting?

Comment: Thanks Ahmad, I am targetting pdf, and ms office files.

Comment: if for viewing only, I would consider web view, try that and let me know.

Comment: Thanks sir, but will that require being online? So it wont work in airplane mode etc huh?

Comment: is your file stored remotely or locally?

Comment: It is locally stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try. Create an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` with a `Uri` to the document on external storage and the proper MIME type for whatever sort of file it is. Use `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()` to see if there are any matches. If there are no matches, then the user does not have such an application installed.

Comment: Thank you for the response, i will try that asap.

Comment: Dear @CommonsWare i have updated my question to include what you have advised me to do but still no luck.

Comment: @Ahmad Kayyali: The MIME type for Microsoft Word appears to be `application/msword`. http://filext.com/faq/office_mime_types.php

Answer (score 0):

Don't exactly get your use case, but Google docs will accept and translate those formats to native Gdocs that can be edited on android.

Comment: thank you dartdog, do you have any code snippet explaining your answer?