# No Activity found to handle intent error

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to view a file word as well as .txt file using android as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/usage.txt"), "plain/text");
getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
```

and

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/USAGE_INSTRUCTIONS_FOR_SMART_RESPONDER.doc"), "plain/text");
getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
```

inside a method of an activity. Now, i have ES File Manager installed on my device. But i keep on getting the error:

```
05-09 01:24:53.516: W/System.err(28918): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///android_asset/USAGE_INSTRUCTIONS_FOR_SMART_RESPONDER.doc typ=plain/text flg=0x10000000 }
05-09 01:24:53.516: W/System.err(28918):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1622)
05-09 01:24:53.516: W/System.err(28918):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
05-09 01:24:53.516: W/System.err(28918):    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:949)
05-09 01:24:53.524: W/System.err(28918):    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:931)
05-09 01:24:53.524: W/System.err(28918):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:284)
05-09 01:24:53.524: W/System.err(28918):    at com.pack.android.activity.ResponderActivity.onHelpMenuSelected(ResponderActivity.java:1733)
05-09 01:24:53.524: W/System.err(28918):    at com.pack.android.activity.ResponderActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(ResponderActivity.java:1711)
05-09 01:24:53.532: W/System.err(28918):    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2548)
05-09 01:24:53.532: W/System.err(28918):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:980)
05-09 01:24:53.532: W/System.err(28918):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
05-09 01:24:53.532: W/System.err(28918):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
05-09 01:24:53.539: W/System.err(28918):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
05-09 01:24:53.539: W/System.err(28918):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.onItemClick(MenuPopupHelper.java:156)
05-09 01:24:53.539: W/System.err(28918):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
05-09 01:24:53.539: W/System.err(28918):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
05-09 01:24:53.547: W/System.err(28918):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
05-09 01:24:53.547: W/System.err(28918):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3423)
05-09 01:24:53.547: W/System.err(28918):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-09 01:24:53.547: W/System.err(28918):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-09 01:24:53.547: W/System.err(28918):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-09 01:24:53.555: W/System.err(28918):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-09 01:24:53.555: W/System.err(28918):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-09 01:24:53.555: W/System.err(28918):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-09 01:24:53.555: W/System.err(28918):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-09 01:24:53.555: W/System.err(28918):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-09 01:24:53.563: W/System.err(28918):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and

```
05-09 01:29:43.071: W/System.err(28918): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///android_asset/usage.txt typ=plain/text flg=0x10000000 }
05-09 01:29:43.071: W/System.err(28918):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1622)
05-09 01:29:43.078: W/System.err(28918):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
05-09 01:29:43.078: W/System.err(28918):    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:949)
05-09 01:29:43.086: W/System.err(28918):    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:931)
05-09 01:29:43.086: W/System.err(28918):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:284)
05-09 01:29:43.086: W/System.err(28918):    at com.pack.android.activity.ResponderActivity.onHelpMenuSelected(ResponderActivity.java:1748)
05-09 01:29:43.086: W/System.err(28918):    at com.pack.android.activity.ResponderActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(ResponderActivity.java:1711)
05-09 01:29:43.094: W/System.err(28918):    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2548)
05-09 01:29:43.094: W/System.err(28918):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:980)
05-09 01:29:43.094: W/System.err(28918):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
05-09 01:29:43.094: W/System.err(28918):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
05-09 01:29:43.094: W/System.err(28918):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
05-09 01:29:43.102: W/System.err(28918):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.onItemClick(MenuPopupHelper.java:156)
05-09 01:29:43.102: W/System.err(28918):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
05-09 01:29:43.102: W/System.err(28918):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
05-09 01:29:43.102: W/System.err(28918):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
05-09 01:29:43.110: W/System.err(28918):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3423)
05-09 01:29:43.110: W/System.err(28918):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-09 01:29:43.110: W/System.err(28918):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-09 01:29:43.118: W/System.err(28918):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-09 01:29:43.118: W/System.err(28918):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-09 01:29:43.118: W/System.err(28918):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-09 01:29:43.118: W/System.err(28918):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-09 01:29:43.125: W/System.err(28918):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-09 01:29:43.125: W/System.err(28918):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-09 01:29:43.125: W/System.err(28918):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have got these 2 files in my assets folder but still can't open it!
Any help would be great !

**EDIT**

using proper **MIME_TYPE** does resolve the error but now i am getting another error :

```
05-09 01:42:27.647: W/System.err(29614): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /android_asset/USAGE_INSTRUCTIONS_FOR_SMART_RESPONDER.doc: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
05-09 01:42:27.647: W/System.err(29614):    at com.tf.fastole2.CompoundBinaryUtil.openRandomAccessFile(CompoundBinaryUtil.java:15)
05-09 01:42:27.647: W/System.err(29614):    at com.tf.fastole2.TFOleFileSystem.openFileSystem(TFOleFileSystem.java:81)
05-09 01:42:27.647: W/System.err(29614):    at com.tf.fastole2.TFOleFsFactory.openFileSystem(TFOleFsFactory.java:32)
05-09 01:42:27.647: W/System.err(29614):    at com.tf.write.filter.CheckFileType.isHwp50(CheckFileType.java:240)
05-09 01:42:27.655: W/System.err(29614):    at com.tf.write.filter.CheckFileType.getType(CheckFileType.java:35)
05-09 01:42:27.655: W/System.err(29614):    at com.tf.thinkdroid.write.viewer.action.Open$2.run(Unknown Source)
05-09 01:42:27.655: W/System.err(29614):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-09 01:42:27.655: W/System.err(29614): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /android_asset/USAGE_INSTRUCTIONS_FOR_SMART_RESPONDER.doc: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
05-09 01:42:27.655: W/System.err(29614):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
05-09 01:42:27.655: W/System.err(29614):    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:118)
05-09 01:42:27.655: W/System.err(29614):    at com.tf.fastole2.CompoundBinaryUtil.openRandomAccessFile(CompoundBinaryUtil.java:11)
05-09 01:42:27.655: W/System.err(29614):    ... 6 more
05-09 01:42:27.655: W/System.err(29614): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
05-09 01:42:27.655: W/System.err(29614):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
05-09 01:42:27.655: W/System.err(29614):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
05-09 01:42:27.655: W/System.err(29614):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
05-09 01:42:27.655: W/System.err(29614):    ... 8 more
05-09 01:42:27.655: W/System.err(29614): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /android_asset/USAGE_INSTRUCTIONS_FOR_SMART_RESPONDER.doc: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
05-09 01:42:27.655: W/System.err(29614):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
05-09 01:42:27.655: W/System.err(29614):    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:118)
05-09 01:42:27.655: W/System.err(29614):    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:150)
05-09 01:42:27.655: W/System.err(29614):    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:130)
05-09 01:42:27.655: W/System.err(29614):    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:103)
05-09 01:42:27.655: W/System.err(29614):    at com.tf.io.CachedZipFile$RealZipFileImpl.<init>(CachedZipFile.java:274)
05-09 01:42:27.655: W/System.err(29614):    at com.tf.io.CachedZipFile$RealZipFileImpl.<init>(CachedZipFile.java:269)
05-09 01:42:27.655: W/System.err(29614):    at com.tf.io.CachedZipFile.create(CachedZipFile.java:61)
05-09 01:42:27.655: W/System.err(29614):    at com.tf.io.CachedZipFile.create(CachedZipFile.java:37)
05-09 01:42:27.655: W/System.err(29614):    at com.tf.write.filter.CheckFileType.isDocx(CheckFileType.java:322)
05-09 01:42:27.655: W/System.err(29614):    at com.tf.write.filter.CheckFileType.getType(CheckFileType.java:47)
05-09 01:42:27.655: W/System.err(29614):    at com.tf.thinkdroid.write.viewer.action.Open$2.run(Unknown Source)
05-09 01:42:27.655: W/System.err(29614):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-09 01:42:27.655: W/System.err(29614): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
05-09 01:42:27.663: W/System.err(29614):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
05-09 01:42:27.663: W/System.err(29614):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
05-09 01:42:27.663: W/System.err(29614):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
05-09 01:42:27.663: W/System.err(29614):    ... 12 more
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is with the MIME type: `text/plain`

Comment: @Adithya The MIME type for Microsoft Word appears to be application/msword. Did you tried usingapplication/msword ?

Source:http://stackoverflow.com/a/4775394/801437

Comment: specifying application/msword resolves the error but now i am getting another error: Please see my Edited question.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are trying to give access via intents to 3rd party applications that doesn't have permission to access your files.
**Android's Security Model doesn't allow any other app to access your private data (assets/resources ....)** root here is an exception.

So to make your file available to such apps consider copying your files to a public directory [CacheDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir%28%29) maybe the most suitable option.

by doing so you can use intents to view your data the way you are using them right now.
for more about copying files to external dir look here:

[Android: how to copy files in assets to sdcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447477/android-how-to-copy-files-in-assets-to-sdcard)

Also while at it take a look at [Android's Security Model](http://source.android.com/tech/security/)

**P.S don't forget about WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** permession..

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You should use `text/plain` instead of `plain/text`.

Answer (score 0):

As is mentioned in the exception log,

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /android_asset/USAGE_INSTRUCTIONS_FOR_SMART_RESPONDER.doc: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

its not able to find the file. Verify if the file is indeed there in that location. Also, as Brigham mentioned, use text/plain.

Answer (score 0):

Exception says that File not exist. Watch that you are pointing to /android_asset/ folder in internal memory.

Are you sure that you not put this file on SDCard?