# Start Activity with action, but no category

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to start an activity defined in another apk, in its AndroidManifest.xml, it defines an activity and with an action, but no category defined.

The format is like

```
<activity name="...">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="action name">
    <intent-filter>
</activity>
```

My code is following

```
Intent i = new Intent("action name");
startActivity(i);
```

However my apk crashed with uncaught ActivityNotFound exception, the logs read
No Activity found to handle intent ... "

Any thoughts?

Thanx a lot.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Looking at the [Intent documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html), it says **Note also the DEFAULT category supplied here: this is required for the `Context.startActivity` method to resolve your activity when its component name is not explicitly specified.** If the activity's IntentFilter definition does not include that category then you can't start it with startActivity. Try using the [setClassName](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setClassName%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method, and pass it the package class and the activity class you're trying to launch.

Answer (score 16):

you cannot have empty category when you use startActivity(...).

add a default category and this will do the job:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="action name" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the activity you are starting in your Manifest. Make sure you have provided same `<intent-action` (and name of the activity) that has the activity in the other apk you want to start.

[android: how do i open another app from my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923265/android-how-do-i-open-another-app-from-my-app)

Comment: Can you give more details about the intent definition in manifest? How do I include activity in the other apk in my manifest?