# How to register an Intent to be discovered by other applications?

Tags: android

I'm developing an application that needs to be called by another application. Both applications will be installed in my `Android` device. I need application A to search for application B and the call it.

I have the following requirement from my company:

> an intent must also have its type attribute set to `application/mycompanyname.com` and it will be discovered using `PackageManager.queryIntentActivities(Intent intent, int flags)` with the intent described to see if any activity is available.

But I'm having trouble to register it. Since now I've tried this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.testpublishintent"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".ReceiverDemo">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="marakana.intent.action.ReceiverDemo" />
          </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>

</manifest>
```

And I'm looking for all installed apps like this:

```
void GetInstalledAppList()
{
  final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
  mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
  final List pkgAppsList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);
  for (Object object : pkgAppsList) 
  {
    ResolveInfo info = (ResolveInfo) object;
    Drawable icon    = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(info.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
    String strAppName   = info.activityInfo.applicationInfo.publicSourceDir.toString();
    String strPackageName  = info.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName.toString();
    final String title  = (String)((info != null) ? getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(info.activityInfo.applicationInfo) : "???");
   }
 }
```

But I don't know if this is correct as I can see the installed app but not instantiate it. Can anybody correct me please?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have a look to [this page](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html) of the documentation, they're basically explaining all what you need.

It works this way: you register the activity you want to start by defining some `IntentFilter` in its `Manifest` and then you start this intent from the original `Activity`.

But, if you want a custom intent, I'd have a look to do this [StackOverflow Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11008893/2545832) (you didn't say which kind of intent you wanted)