# Install apk after download with download manager and exit from app

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-download-manager

i have created an android app and from server if any new version had released it will automatically start downloading by using inbuilt 'download manager' . for auto install after finish the download i have created a broadcast receiver to inform that download has finished and completed and then i start to install it. it works fine during i stay in app and don't close it. but my problem is when i close the application . so after finishing the download i want to automatically install it. but i wont happen. what should i do for this issue?

```
    private void download(String link) {
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(link));
    request.setDescription("new version");
    request.setTitle("app name");
    request.setMimeType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(getApplicationContext(), Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "myapk.apk");
    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

    downloadID = dm.enqueue(request);


    br = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
            String action = i.getAction();

            if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {

                DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
                query.setFilterById(downloadID);

                Cursor downloadResult = dm.query(query);

                if (downloadResult.moveToFirst()) {
                    int statusColumnIndex = downloadResult.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                    int status = downloadResult.getInt(statusColumnIndex);

                    if (status == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
                        //download completed successfully
                        int localFileNameId = downloadResult.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME);

                        String downloadPathFile = downloadResult.getString(localFileNameId);
                        String downloadPathDir = downloadPathFile.substring(0, downloadPathFile.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                        String downloadName = downloadPathFile.substring(downloadPathFile.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

                        Log.i("name =", downloadName);

                        File file = new File(downloadPathDir);
                        File[] files = file.listFiles();
                        for (File f : files) {
                            if (f.isFile() && f.exists() && !f.getName().equals(downloadName)) {
                                f.delete();
                            }
                        }

                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(downloadPathFile)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        unregisterReceiver(br);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));

}
```

Comment: how or where are you handling the broadcast receiver?

Comment: i put my broadcast receiver in code and register it inside my code

Comment: so just to be sure you are not registering the broadcast receiver in the manifest right?

Comment: yes i did not register it in manifest, i have update the question and put my code.

Comment: Can you try to set download destination via setPublicExternalDir() and see how it goes? PackageInstaller requires file read permissions, which may not be set by downloadmanager when using default destination folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

in your manifest

```
<receiver android:name="packageName.DownloadReceiver" android:exported="true"> 
    <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"/> 
    </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

and then in `DownloadReceiver.java` add the logic to handle auto install for example

```
public class DownloadReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
            // add your logic here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i did it same as you said but still after finish download nothing happen

Comment: hmmm... can you update your question to see the receiver? i think i have an idea of what is going on

Comment: you were right. but please update your answer with this.                    <receiver
            android:name="packageName.DownloadReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>.                           after update the answer i will check it as currect answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

to install the apk check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically)

to exit the app use `finish();`