# Target action bar item from navigation drawer

Tags: java, android

I am currently working on an app that i implemented a toolbar and a search functionality on the toolbar with a searchview to filter list views which is working fine.
I also have a navigation drawer whereby i also want one of its items to do exactly what the search functionality is doing on the toolbar. How do implement an intent to lead me to `SearchView`on toolbar when `search`item is clicked from navigation drawer.

menu_main for toolbar

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/viewMode"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_view_compact_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/view" />
    <item
// my search functionality
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:actionViewClass= "android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:title="@string/search" />


</menu>
```

activity_navdrawer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_notes"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_note_add_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/first_layout" />

        <item
// search functionality which should lead me to searchview on toolbar
            android:id="@+id/nav_search"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/third_layout" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="@string/app_communicate">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_share_black_24dp"
                android:title="@string/app_share" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_send"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_email_black_24dp"
                android:title="@string/app_send" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

from main activity

```
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      // Handling navigation view item clicks here.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if(id == R.id.nav_notes) {
                Intent noteIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(noteIntent);

            } else if(id == R.id.nav_search) {
MenuItem searchMenuItem = mOptionsMenu.findItem(R.id.search);
            searchMenuItem.expandActionView();
               // what should i implement here?


            }

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        }
     @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(`final` Menu menu) {


  mOptionsMenu = menu;
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
           inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            SearchManager searchManager =
                    (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
             searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
            searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                    ArrayAdapter<Note> arrayAdapter = (ArrayAdapter<Note>) mListNotes.getAdapter();
                    arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                    return false;
                }
            });
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code below:

```
private Menu mOptionsMenu;

    ...

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
        mOptionsMenu = menu;
        ...
    }

    ...

    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    ...
    } else if(id == R.id.nav_search) {
        MenuItem searchMenuItem = mOptionsMenu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
        searchMenuItem.expandActionView();
    }
    ...
```

Comment: it doesn't work as expected sir. it just does null. is there not a way i can open the toolbar's search view from navigation drawer?

Comment: What do you mean by it just does null?

Comment: it just displays main content when clicked. doesn't open up searchview menu item on toolbar

Comment: Use `R.id.search` instead of `R.id.menu_search`.

Comment: exactly what i did. you can check my edited code above. gives me same result

Comment: Well the solution I suggested works for me. Can you post your `onCreateOptionsMenu` function?

Answer (score 0):

Add `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />` to your search activity in manifest. Then do this:

```
else if(id == R.id.nav_search) {

       startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH));

    }
```

If this works, courtesy - [Start Activity Using Custom Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921451/start-activity-using-custom-action)

Comment: i want to open the search view item on the toolbar. your code is sending an intent away from the app.

Comment: Okay, cut the `startActivity()` and do:
`if(mySearchView.requestFocus()) {
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
}`
`mySearchView` should be replaced with your `SearchView` object

Comment: it just displays main content when clicked. doesn't open up searchview menu item on toolbar