# uri to call an application installed in the device

Tags: android

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("com.dynamixsoftware.printershare.print");
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(uri);
    intent.setPackage("com.dynamixsoftware.printershare.print");
    intent.setType("application/pdf");
    startActivity(intent);
    return true;
```

This is the code I am using to call another application from my application. I think the uri I am mentioning is incorrect. In that case, I dont know how to get the right one. Else, I don't know what's going wrong. I have no error in the logcat and the application force closes.

Comment: The answer here may help you find a solution, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923265/android-how-do-i-open-another-app-from-my-app

 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it,

```
Intent intent =  getPackageManager()                    
.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.dynamixsoftware.printershare.print");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: 01-11 08:55:28.452: E/AndroidRuntime(341): java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: 01-11 08:55:28.452: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1374)
01-11 08:55:28.452: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
01-11 08:55:28.452: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
01-11 08:55:28.452: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at com.imagemanip.MainActivity.queuePictureStreamForPrinting(MainActivity.java:164)
01-11 08:55:28.452: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at com.imagemanip.MainActivity.saveCanvasPictureToTempFile(MainActivity.java:122)

Comment: 01-11 08:55:28.452: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at com.imagemanip.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:63)
01-11 08:55:28.452: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
01-11 08:55:28.452: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
01-11 08:55:28.452: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-11 08:55:28.452: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-11 08:55:28.452: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)